# Are taxi drivers in Thailand allowed to charge customers for writing a receipt?

Tags: fees, transportation, receipts, thailand

I [read](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/185380/1810):

> Oh and if you're looking for a receipt – the receipt printer is hidden, right on the dashboard, under a towel. It might not have paper anyway, and if they write a receipt for you, they'll charge you for it. (author: [dda](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/138870/dda))

Are taxi drivers in Thailand allowed to charge customers for writing a receipt?

Comment: I suspect it's the other way round: If you don't need a receipt, it's cheaper, because then they don't need to officially declare the ride as income, thus don't pay taxes or fees on it.

Comment: @PMF, or, anyway, cheaper for them, etc. Maybe they pass along the overhead... :)

Comment: Probably you just asked out if curiosity, but if you are a tourist in Thailand, the implied attitude will prob get you into trouble.

Comment: @lalala people who pay give money to scammers are why scammers exist.

Comment: I am not saying to give money to scammers, dont do it. But approaching anything from a 'what is the law' angle can go south fast.